# can I install 32-bit jvm on 64-bit operation system?

Tags: java, jvm

can I install 32-bit jvm on 64-bit operation system?

can I instanll 64-bit jvm on 32-bit operation system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. In some cases it is necessary. For instance for 32-bit apps on the same operating system which require JVM to work. These 32-bit apps are unable to use 64-bit JVM and require 32-bit JVM installed.

Installing 64-bit JVM on 32-bit OS is not possible, it just won't work.

Comment: +1 Pure Java programs are not 32-bit or 64-bit specific and you should be able to run it on either JVM, but they might use JNI libraries which are 32-bit or 64-bit specific and will require a JVM which is the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can install 32 bit JVM in 64 bit operating system but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Ya offcourse you can install 32bit JVM in 64 bit OS, as downward compatibility is provided my OS.

**2.** But you can Not install a 64bit JVM in 32bit OS.